# си /proc/self/stat чтение 4 поля

Tags: linux, c

Здравствуйте. Интересует следующий вопрос. Как грамотно получить 4 поле в файле /proc/self/stat (4 поле это pid родителя процесса). в man proc написано что первые три параметра это %d %s %c(если использовать функцию scanf). Наш четвертый это %d. Но если использовать в имени файла пробелы, скобки, другие допустимые символы, то в простейшем случае а .out scanf(%*d%*s%*c%d)

cat /proc/31707/stat имеет следующий вывод

> 31707 (kworker/u64:1) S 2 0 0 0 -1 69247072 0 0 0
>   0 0 80 0 0 20 0 1 0 128062368 0 0 4294967295 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2147483647
>   0 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 324 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Поэтому встает вопрос как правильно прочитать pid родителя заданного процесса(не нашего). Насколько я знаю апи таких нет.

Comment: Прочитайте status, там отдельная строка и написано что это такое. Но вопрос действительно интересный, ибо другого API действительно нет и стандартный ps пользуется этими же файлами proc. Исходники правда у него большие влом искать как он это делает

Comment: Да, `int ppid, n = fscanf(in, "%*d %*s %*s %d", &ppid);` вполне подходит (собственно, его вы и написали). И в чем тогда вопрос-то?

Comment: @avp А что сделает такой scanf когда в имени программы пробел. Я проверил, в stat пробел так же присутствует никак не экранирован и скобки круглые в имени файла так же спокойно пишутся в файле ... И кстати назвать программу `program) S 45` никто не мешает

Comment: @Mike, а, понял проблему (вот ведь дурь с пробелами в именах, какому уроду пришло в голову так делать? (а остальные подхватили...)). Решается, очевидно, посимвольным чтением с подсчетом скобочек до чтения закрывающей и равенства счетчика их баланса нулю. Потом `fscanf()`

Comment: @avp люблю файлы вот так называть a. out ))))) ха-ха

Comment: наверное всё-таки придётся читать посимвольно. хотя можно попробовать читать с конца

Comment: Ну, это из серии -- "создаем себе проблемы, а потом героически их преодалеваем" или "чем бы дитя не тешилось..."

Comment: ищем скобку закрывающуюся по s = strchr, а потом scanf(s, ....

Comment: @avp Получается надо тупо читать до последней закрывающейся скобки строки

Comment: @avp я просто пример привела. мы же не можем гарантировать что-то кто-то не окажется дитем? а вообще наверное лучше будет искать первую и  последнии скобки в строке. изобрести небольшой велосипед.

Comment: @Max Timakov я же говорила, что ppid нужен произвольного процесса.

Comment: @Mike, в общем, да. Но, наверное самой простой способ уже предложил @ maint / Прочесть строку и  `strchr()`, только надо не strchr, а **rstrchr(str, ')')**, т.е. с конца.

Comment: Читаю исходники пакета procps (обеспечивающего обычную утилиту `ps`), самое начало функции stat2proc (на входе строка прочитанная из файла): `    S = strchr(S, '(') + 1;    tmp = strrchr(S, ')'); ` комментарии думаю излишни ...

Comment: А если в имени файла будет скобка...

Comment: @KoVadim (kworker/u64:1) имя файла офрмляется в скобках. ТО есть даже если файл будет называть 123.хохо)))))((())))) то он будет заключен в скобки ( 123.хохо)))))((())))) ) (без пробелов естественно, это для наглядности)

Comment: Да, я понял, там просто дальше скобок не может быть. (букву r не приметил в имени функции). Но смелое, как по мне, решение.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -el | awk '{print $5}'
```

Если нужен PPID конкретного процесса - вставьте соответcтвующий grep между ps и awk

Comment: а если в имени пробелы оно тоже работать будет? О чём собственно всё обсуждение в комментариях под вопросом.

Comment: Вообще-то, в вопросе речь о Си, но если уж на шелле, то так: `sed 's/^.*)//' /proc/$PID/stat | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: _getppid() returns the process ID of the parent of the calling process._

Comment: **Вообще-то, в вопросе речь о Си** - см. предыдущее замечание - просто неудачно нажал "Enter". Я решил что автору нужен скрипт, т.к. он читает ФАЙЛ в каталоге proc. Если же речь идёт о ppid текущего процесса, то самое простое решение - getppid().

Comment: Если же речь идёт о ppid некоего "другого" процесса,  то искать его по имени исполняемого файла довольно рискованно:
- Таких процессов может быть несколько
- Это может быть зомби

Так что проблема с пробелом в имени файла - не самая большая, на мой взгляд.